# Variadic function in a monad

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have a type family of variadic functions:

```
type family (~~>) (argTypes :: [Type]) (result :: Type) :: Type where
'[]       ~~> r = r
(t ': ts) ~~> r = t -> (ts ~~> r)

infixr 0 ~~>
```

I want a variadic function which applies some monadic action (say print) to all its arguments:

```
class Foo (ts :: [Type]) where
foo :: ts ~~> IO ()

instance Foo '[] where
    foo = pure ()

instance (Show t, Foo ts) => Foo (t ': ts) where
    foo t = print t >> foo @ts
```

Usual monadic composition doesn't work here.
`(>>)` has type `IO () -> IO () -> IO ()`. I need to use something of type `IO () -> (ts ~~> IO ()) -> ts ~~> IO ()` to compose `print t` and `foo @ts` there.

Is it possible to write such function at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuation passing style gives direct access to the result of a computation.

Another way would be to build a type class to iterate composition, but it's cumbersome.

```
 {-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Foo t where
  foo_ :: (IO () -> IO ()) -> t

instance (Show a, Foo t) => Foo (a -> t) where
  foo_ k a = foo_ (\continue -> k (print a >> continue))

instance Foo (IO ()) where
  foo_ k = k (return ())

foo :: Foo t => t
foo = foo_ id

main :: IO ()
main = foo () (Just "bar") [()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to write function `IO () -> (ts ~~> IO ()) -> ts ~~> IO ()`

```
-- | Perform first action `m a` then pass its result to a function `(a -> ts ~~> mb)`
--   which returns variadic function and return that function.
class BindV (m :: Type -> Type) a b (ts :: [Type]) where
    bindV :: m a -> (a -> ts ~~> m b) -> ts ~~> m b

instance (Monad m) => BindV m a b '[] where
    bindV ma f = ma >>= f

instance (BindV m a b ts) => BindV m a b (t ': ts) where
    bindV ma f x = bindV @m @a @b @ts ma ((flip f) x)

-- | Monadic composition that discards result of the first action.
thenV :: forall (m :: Type -> Type) a b (ts :: [Type]).
    (BindV m a b ts) => 
    m a -> (ts ~~> m b) -> ts ~~> m b
thenV ma f = bindV @m @a @b @ts ma (\_ -> f)
```

Thus instance in question become:

```
instance (Show t, Foo ts, BindV IO () () ts) => Foo (t ': ts) where
    foo t = thenV @IO @() @() @ts (print t) (foo @ts)
```

I wish I could write `thenV` and `bindV` as an operator but `TypeApplications` doesn't work with operators.